# Callbacks in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, callback

I have an user interactive animation in matlab where a shape is translated and rotates across a plot and the user has to click on it.  If they click on it, their score is incremented and if not, the animation stops.  For some reason the program does not seem to be registering the clicks from the user and I am unsure why.  I have posted the code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Animation Function:

```
function movingPolygon
global gUserHitPolygon;
global gCurrentXVertices;
global gCurrentYVertices;
gUserHitPolygon = true;
global gScore;
nSides =4;
%Polar points
r=1;
theta = pi/nSides * (1:2:2*nSides-1);

%Cartesisn points
x0 = r * cos(theta);
y0 = r * sin(theta);
nFrames = 100;
xx = linspace(0,10, nFrames);
yy = xx;

rr = linspace(0, 2*pi, nFrames);
h = figure;
set(h,'WindowButtonDownFcn',   @mouseDownCallback);
i=1;
while gUserHitPolygon

    rX = [cos(rr(i)), -sin(rr(i))];
    rY = [sin(rr(i)), cos(rr(i))];

    x1 = rX * [x0; y0];
    y1 = rY * [x0; y0];

    x2= x1 + xx(i);
    y2= y1 + yy(i);
    gCurrentXVertices=x2;
    gCurrentYVertices=y2;
    y=fill(x2, y2, 'b');

    xlim([0,10]); ylim([0,10]);
    hold on;
    pause(0.000000003);
    delete(y);
    title(sprintf('Score: %d', gScore));
    i=i+1;
    if i>nFrames
        i=1;
    end
end
end
```

Callback Function

```
function mouseDownCallback(~,~)

global gUserHitPolygon;
global gCurrentXVertices;
global gCurrentYVertices;
global gScore;
gScore=0;

xVertices = gCurrentXVertices;
yVertices = gCurrentYVertices;

% if we have valid (so non-empty) sets of x- and y-vertices then...
if isempty(xVertices) && isempty(yVertices)

    % get the coordinate on the current axis
    coordinates = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
    coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);

    % if the coordinate is not in the polygon, then change the
    % flag
    if inpolygon(coordinates(1),coordinates(2),xVertices,yVertices)
        gUserHitPolygon = false;
    else
        gScore=gScore+1;
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 issues with your code.

First, you initialise the value of `gScore` as 0 inside the callback function. That means that  every time the mouse is clicked, `gScore` is set to 0. Instead, initialise it to 0 in the main function, just after you define it as a global variable, and just call `global gScore` in the callback.

Secondly, you are using an `if` statement to determine whether you have a valid set of coordinates from the click, and if so, you want to execute some code. However, your `if` statement is testing whether the inputs are empty, and only if they are is it running. Change the `if` statement to

```
if ~isempty(xVertices) && ~isempty(yVertices)
```

which will evaluate to `1` if you have valid (non-empty) inputs.

Thirdly, your test for whether the user clicks inside or outside the polygon has the same problem. If the user clicks inside the polygon, `inpolygon` will be true, and so you will execute `gUserHitPolygon = false;`, rather than the intended `gScore=gScore+1;`. To fix this, again, negate your condition:

```
if ~inpolygon(coordinates(1),coordinates(2),xVertices,yVertices)
```